# Linux pv | gzip doesn't delete original file

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

I'm pretty new to unix so go easy.

Normally `gzip file` replaces file with file.gz (which i'm guessing is: create file.gz then rm file).

I have some rather large files I'm compressing and I like to see the progress and eta so I use

```
pv -tpreb file | gzip -9 > file.gz
```

But now I am left with the original file along with the new file.gz. I don't want to have to rm the original manually.

What should I do?

Comment: It seems that you cannot.  `pv` reads the files and pipes to `gzip` therefore `gzip` gets its input from `stdin`. Of course `gzip` will have no clue that the input actually comes from `file` and therefore cannot delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kenneth L mentioned in his comment, there's no way to accomplish this with the tools you're using, due to the way `pv` pipes `file` to `gzip`.

A kludgy workaround would be to delete the original file immediately after compressing it:

```
pv -tpreb file | gzip -9 > file.gz && rm file
```

You can compress multiple files in the same archive and delete the originals with the following commands:

```
export FILES='foo bar quux'
tar c $FILES | pv -tpreb | gzip -9 > zip.gz && rm $FILES
```

and decompress those files with `tar xvzf zip.gz`.

Comment: I did not know you could append commands to eachother with &&. Thanks! I'd +1 but don't have the neccessary requirements from SE.

Comment: As an addition, I edited my bash profile with the function `gz() { pv -tpreb $1 | gzip -9 > $1.gz && rm $1 }` allowing me to call the shortcut `gz file`. I hope that's useful to someone. An accompanying gunzip shortcut is a good idea too.